# Cannot execute standalone webassembly file with wasmer

Tags: c, rust, compiler-errors, webassembly, emscripten

I wrote a matrix multiplication program in C and compiled it using Emscripten with the following command

`emcc matrix.c -o matrix.wasm -s STANDALONE_WASM`

And the C program is as follows,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int matrix() {
    int a[101][101];
    int b[101][101];
    int r[101][101];
    for(int i = 0; i<101; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<101; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand()%1000+1;
            b[i][j] = rand()%1000+1;
        }
    }   
    for(int i = 0; i<101; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<101; j++) {
            r[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k<101; k++) {
                r[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    clock_t start, finish;
    double  duration;
    start = clock();
    matrix();
    finish = clock();
    duration = (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("computing duration: %fs\n", duration);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I used [wasmer](https://github.com/wasmerio/) to directly run this webassembly file:

`wasmer matrix.wasm`.

It returned the expected result. Then I wanted to execute this file with a specific function, that is the export function in webassembly file.

I used [wasm2wat](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt) to translate this executable file into a wat file.Then I found `(export "_start" (func 6))`. By the way, I did not found any code about export the matrix function. Then I executed the matrix.wasm with the command:

`wasmer matrix.wasm -i _start`

However, the error appeared. It said:

```
error: failed to run `matrix.wasm`
╰─> 1: Error while importing "wasi_snapshot_preview1"."clock_time_get": unknown import. Expected Function(FunctionType { params: [I32, I64, I32], results: [I32] })
```

Then I tried Rust to write a simple program, which just contained a main function and a add function. I used cargo to compile it to two kinds of targets, which is wasm32-unknown-unknown and wasm32-wasi. I compiled them into wat file. This time I found `(export "add" (func $add.command_export))`. When I executed the wasm32-wasi programm with

`wasmer add.wasm -i add`

There was also errors appearing. It said:

```
error: failed to run `hello.wasm`
╰─> 1: Error while importing "wasi_snapshot_preview1"."args_get": unknown import. Expected Function(FunctionType { params: [I32, I32], results: [I32] })
```

I could execute the file whose target was wasm32-unknown-unknown correctly but I could not use lib function in this kind of target.

I think there are something wrong with my wasm32-wasi file but I do not know why it is and how to deal with it. Could you please tell me how I can call an export function in wasm32-wasi file and how I can call a lib function in wasm32-unknown-unknown file. Also I have some questions about why  I use Emscripten compile the C file but the matrix function does not export in wat file. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible you have to specify some option to enable WASI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers will often inline functions and remove code that isn't used, this is why your C program ends up with everything inside a `_start` function. As [explained in the FAQ](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-do-functions-in-my-c-c-source-code-vanish-when-i-compile-to-javascript-and-or-i-get-no-functions-to-process) you may list functions to export using `emcc -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=_main,_matrix` in order to prevent them from being inlined or removed. Adding this results in a wasm module with the function correctly exported.

As for running functions directly, the [source code for wasmer run](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/blob/cdab1b2e705d933030e8edafd6538ea29ddc8bc2/lib/cli/src/commands/run.rs#L95-L108) has logic to determine which runtime environment should be exposed to the module. However, if you pass `-i function`, it entirely skips the environment setup and runs your function directly. In this case, the modules fails to initialize because it imports functions from WASI (in order to write things to the console, and get the current clock time).

I believe the reason why `wasm32-unknown-unknown` works is that it doesn't link to any runtime, and implements dummy interfaces for things that it can't simulate (all filesystem calls result in errors, etc.)

In summary, `wasmer run -i function` isn't meant to run functions from modules that have imports, it might be possible to patch `wasmer-cli` for that, but I'm not sure if it would work across all runtime environments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I find that [Wasmtime](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime) can execute the imported function successfully.